# Getting "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version"

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can someone please run their eye over my coding to find why I am getting this:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I know it will be something really simple but I can not see it.

```
<body>
<?php
//connect to database//
$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "***");
if (!$dbc)
die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

//select database//
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("tafe", $dbc );
if (!$db_selected)
die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

// initialise variables to store form control values
$Name = "";
$Address = "";
$Phone = "";
$Mobile = "";
$Email = "";


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") // if form has been posted
{  
// initialise variables to store posted values
$ContactID = $_POST["ContactID"];
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$Address = $_POST["Address"];
$Phone = $_POST["Phone"];
$Mobile = $_POST["Mobile"];
$Email = $_POST["Email"];

//build sql insert statement
$qry = "UPDATE contacts SET Name = '" . $Name . "', Address = '" . $Address . "', Phone = '" . $Phone . "', Mobile = '" . $Mobile . "', Email = '" . $Email . "' WHERE ContactID =" . $ContactID;

// run insert statement against database
$rst = mysql_query($qry, $dbc);

if ($rst)
{
    echo "<b><font color='green'>The contact has been updated.</font></b>";
    echo "</br></br>";
    echo "<a href=list-contacts.php>Continue</a>"; 
}

else 

{
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Error: ". mysql_error($dbc) . "</font></b>"; //alert if contact could not be added//
}

}


else // if form has not been posted
{
// build sql statement
$qry = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = " . $_GET["ContactID"];


// run select statement
$rst = mysql_query($qry, $dbc);

if ($rst)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rst); // fetch row and place column values into respective place holder variable 

    $Name = $row["Name"];
    $Address = $row["Address"];
    $Phone = $row["Phone"];
    $Mobile = $row["Mobile"];
    $Email = $row["Email"];
}

else // in case of an error
{
    echo "<b><font color='red'>Error: ". mysql_error($dbc) . "</font></b>"; 
} // end of nested else statement ?>

<form name="editcontact" method="post" action="edit-contact.php"> 
<table border="1" cellpadding="2">
<caption> Caption 5</caption>

<!--Name Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Name">Name</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $Name ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="1"/>
</td>
</tr>

<!-- Address Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Address">Address</label></td>
<td><textarea name="Address" cols="45" rows="5" tabindex="2"><?php echo $Address?></textarea></td>
</tr>

<!--Phone Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Phone">Phone</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $Phone ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="3" /> </td>
</tr>

<!--Mobile Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Mobile">Mobile</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mobile" value="<?php echo $Mobile ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="4" /> </td>
</tr>

<!--Email Input-->
<tr>
<td><label for="Email">Email</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $Email ?>" size="30" maxlength="50" tabindex="5" /></td>
</tr>

<!--Submit Button-->
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" tabindex="6"/>      
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>



<?php
} // end of main else statement

mysql_free_result($rst); //free memory//

?>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Are you sure Name and Address do not contain ' ? And are you sure $ContactID is an integer?

Comment: What does `var_dump($qry);` show?

Comment: I copy and pasted my coding exactly so unsure where you mean $Name and $Address containing '. 
ContactID is definitely an integer in  my sql database

Comment: var_dump($qry); returned NULL, what does that mean?

Comment: What I mean is: think what happens if Address is: John's Street 54 for example.

Comment: @user3110441 It means you dump it at the wrong place in your code, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The `$_POST["ContactID"]` returns null, that's why you got that error.
Send the ContactID to the server:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ContactID" value="<?php echo $_GET["ContactID"]; ?>" />
```

There are sevenal problems with your code:

1. Do not use the `mysql_*` functions. They're outdated. Use the `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.
2. Always check the data that was send by the user, or the user may delete your database.
3. Do not use `<b>` and `<font>` tags. It's 2014. Use HTML5, and CSS3.
4. Use `htmlspecialchars()`, or the user will be able to attack your site ([XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))
5. If you use labels, you need to set the input's id.
6. Do not use tables to build up the site. Use floated divs.

This code will work well:

```
 <?php
try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=tafe;host=localhost", "root", "***");
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    die("Cannot connect to database.");
}
function post($name)
{
    return isset($_POST[$name]) ? $_POST[$name] : "";
}
function html($x)
{
    return htmlentities($x, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
if (post("id"))
{  
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE contacts SET Name = :name, Address = :address, Phone = :phone, Mobile = :mobile, Email = :email WHERE ContactID = :id");
    $query->bindParam(":name", post("name"));
    $query->bindParam(":address", post("address"));
    $query->bindParam(":phone", post("phone"));
    $query->bindParam(":mobile", post("mobile"));
    $query->bindParam(":email", post("email"));
    $query->bindParam(":id", post("id"));
    if ($query->execute())
        $message = '<span style="color: green; font-weight: bold;">The contact has been updated.</span><br /><a href="list-contacts.php">Continue</a>';
    else
        $message =  '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">There was an error.</span>';
}
elseif (isset($_GET["ContactID"]))
{
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT Name, Address, Phone, Mobile, Email FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = :id");
    $query->bindParam(":id", $_GET["ContactID"]);
    if ($query->execute())
    {
        if (!$query->rowCount())
            $message = '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">This contact does not exists.</span>';
        else
        {
            $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($row as $k => $v)
                $_POST[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
    else
        $message = '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">There was an error.</span>';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Contact</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        if (isset($message))
            echo "<p>".$message."</p>";
        ?>
        <form action="edit-contact.php" method="post"> 
            <label for="name">Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo html(post("name")) ?>" /><br />
            <label for="address">Address:</label><br />
            <textarea name="address" id="address"><?php echo html(post("address")) ?></textarea><br />
            <label for="phone">Phone:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo html(post("phone")) ?>" /><br />
            <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" value="<?php echo html(post("mobile")) ?>" /><br />
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo html(post("email")) ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />      
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["ContactId"]) ? intval($_GET["ContactId"]) : "0" ?>" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only answer that does not contain some sort of SQL injection, +1!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$qry = "UPDATE contacts SET 
                Name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Name) . "', 
                Address = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Address) . "', 
                Phone = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Phone) . "', 
                Mobile = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Mobile) . "', 
                Email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($Email) . "' 
                WHERE ContactID =" . $ContactID;
```

MAKE SURE in your html form you have a hidden text box or text box with name "ContactID"
Since you are using this in the query and I dont see that within the form.

```
$ContactID = $_POST["ContactID"];
```

NOTE : You are using mysql_* functions  which are deprecated, start using mysqli_* functions or PDO

Comment: Try echo $qry ; and see what you get and post it, may be something not right with your $ContactID

Comment: You should cast `$ContactID` to a integer, otherwise that will contain a SQL injection vulnerability too.

Comment: I get this:
UPDATE contacts SET Name = '', Address = '', Phone = '', Mobile = '', Email = '' WHERE ContactID =Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 

I have also tried WHERE ContactID =" .$_POST['ContactID']; but still get an error message

Comment: Yes meaning the ContactID  is going as null, Now in your form you need to have ContactID I dont see that in your form. Finally you need to do as $ContactID = (int)$_POST["ContactID"]; But before make sure your form has ContactID

Comment: Thanks looks like that was it. I am now getting:

Comment: UPDATE contacts SET Name = '', Address = '', Phone = '', Mobile = '', Email = '' WHERE ContactID =0The contact has been updated.

(when I submit the form)

However still getting the original error message when the page loads..

Comment: no this is wrong..ContactID =0  You need to have ContactID in your form before to get the data as $_POST like you have for others ex : <td><input type="text" name="Phone" value="<?php echo $Phone ?>" size="20" maxlength="20" tabindex="3" /> </td>

Comment: Thank you!!! Adding the (int) infront of any time I was calling the "$ContactID", I was getting the second error on page load because I didn't add the (int) infront of the ContactID further down in my coding. All fixed now, thank you so much for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $qry = "UPDATE contacts 
         SET Name = '" . $Name . "', 
             Address = '" . $Address . "', 
             Phone = '" . $Phone . "', 
             Mobile = '" . $Mobile . "', 
             Email = '" . $Email . "' 
         WHERE ContactID = '" . $ContactID . "' " ;
```

and change to that query also

```
  $qry = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = '" . $_GET['ContactID']."' " ;
```

nB:

1- you should escape your variables by `mysql_real_escape_string()`

2- you should use PDO or MYSQLI instead of MYSQL